# VBA - How to Copy and Paste the last value in a column to another Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel spreadsheet where I want to Find the last value in a column and copy it and paste it to another sheet.

As shown in the below code It works in a way where I am incrementing frequency at the end of the loop and moving the calculations to the right so that I can insert values for next frequency value. The frequency starts at 0.05 and increments by 0.01 every loop and goes up to 1.0.

Before moving the values to the right I am calculating the Absolute Sum and the Square root of the Sum of products for a range as shown in the code below.

```
MAX = 1502
Src = 0
N = 0
Freq = 0.05
Freqmax = 1

Op = ActiveSheet.Range("K2")

For Freq = 0.05 To Freqmax Step 0.01

  For Src = 0 To MAX Step 1

    Inp = ActiveSheet.Range("K" & 2 + Src)

    Op = ma0 * Inp + ma1 * mx1 + ma2 * mx2 - mb1 * my1 - mb2 * my2
    mx2 = mx1
    mx1 = Inp
    my2 = my1
    my1 = Op

    ActiveSheet.Range("$L$1").Value = "Output(" & Freq & ")"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$M$1").Value = "Error(" & Freq & ")"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$N$1").Value = "ErSQ(" & Freq & ")"

    ActiveSheet.Range("L" & 2 + Src) = Op
    ActiveSheet.Range("M" & 2 + Src) = ActiveSheet.Range("L" & 2 + Src) - ActiveSheet.Range("K" & 2 + Src)
    ActiveSheet.Range("N" & 2 + Src) = ActiveSheet.Range("M" & 2 + Src) * ActiveSheet.Range("M" & 2 + Src)

  Next

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastRow1 = ActiveSheet.Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow + 2, "M").Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(ABS(M2:M" & LastRow & "))"
ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow1 + 2, "N").Formula = "=SQR(SUMPRODUCT(ABS(N2:N" & LastRow1 & ")))"

LastValue = ActiveSheet.Range("N" & LastRow1).Value.Copy
Sheets("Sheet5").Activate
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

ActiveSheet.Columns("L:N").Insert Shift:=xlToRight

Next

End Sub
```

I wanted to Copy the Square Root of the sum of products value (`ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow1 + 2, "N").Formula = "=SQR(SUMPRODUCT(ABS(N2:N" & LastRow1 & ")))"`) along with the frequency (`Freq`) value of the current loop into a new sheet and display it as shown below.

[image: Image 1] and so on...

I have tried doing It but to no avail. Can anyone please tell me how do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

substitute

```
LastValue = ActiveSheet.Range("N" & LastRow1).Value.Copy
Sheets("Sheet5").Activate
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

with

```
Sheets("Sheet5").Range("A" & Sheets("Sheet5").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(, 2) = Array(Freq, ActiveSheet.Range("N" & LastRow1 + 2))
```

but to speed things up you'd better use arrays to store values and write them in cells only at the end

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used the line of code given by you, but I encounter > Subscript out of range error. Also, I couldn't figure out how to use arrays to store them. Can I please know how do I fix that?

Comment: which line throws that error? Enquiry all variables values implied in that line by simply hovering the mouse pointer over them or typing `?variableName` (use a real variable name instead of `variableName`...) in the Immediate Window.  As for arrays and ranges, you may want to see [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)

Comment: Sorry my bad, there was something wrong with the formula I had written. All is good. thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

1) It looks like you are always trying to paste the value in cell A1, since this is the cell you select to paste into. SO you will overwrite your value.

I would set up a row counter for the output row and do something like the following.

```
Sheets("Sheet5").Cells(outputrow,1) = ActiveSheet.Range("N" & LastRow1)
```

or

```
Sheets("Sheet5").Cells(outputrow,1) = ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow1,14) 'Column N is the 14th column
```

Note that you don't have to activate the sheet you want to "paste" into. Actually you don't have to have the sheet you are copying from activated either.

2) In general if you are wanting to copy/paste a big area of date directly assigning may be too slow, so you would want to copy->paste
Assuming "Sheet1" is the sheet which contains the data you want to copy and Sheet5 is the sheet you want to paste values into, you can do something like this:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(10, 2), Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(12, 5)).Copy
Worksheets("Sheet5").Cells(13, 11).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 'Paste entire range with cell (13,11) ("K13") being the top left cell of the target
```

This using numbers to represent both rows and columns - so Cells(10,2) represents row 10, column 2 (or B10!)
If you are copying a range of cells you need to specify the "top left" and "bottom right" of the range.

3) It would be even better to set up worksheet variables

```
   Dim wsSource As Worksheet
   Dim wsTarget As Worksheet

   Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")  'Don't forget to Set the worksheet to point at the right sheet!
   Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet5")

   'Copying from B10:E12 in Sheet1 to K13 in Sheet5
   wsSource.Range(wsSource.Cells(10, 2), wsSource.Cells(12, 5)).Copy
   wsTarget.Cells(13, 11).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

OK, that might be a bit more than you were looking for but I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply and for the answer :) really appreciate it :)